# Select certain data in PHP Array

Tags: php

I get the following output when using this line of code `var_dump($ticket->find());` How would I access only the identifiers throughout  ALL objects?

I tried `var_dump($ticket->find()->identifier);` but it returned null.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[9]
      public 'tid' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'uid' => string '22' (length=2)
      public 'subject' => string 'iPhone 8' (length=8)
      public 'issue' => string 'iPhone 8 screen replacement' (length=27)
      public 'device' => string 'iPhone 8' (length=8)
      public 'created' => string '2017-05-25 00:01:11' (length=19)
      public 'identifier' => string '29cd54bf' (length=8)
      public 'status' => string 'New' (length=3)
      public 'tech' => string 'None' (length=4)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[11]
      public 'tid' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'uid' => string '22' (length=2)
      public 'subject' => string 'iPhone 7' (length=8)
      public 'issue' => string 'iPhone 7 screen replacement' (length=27)
      public 'device' => string 'iPhone 7' (length=8)
      public 'created' => string '2017-05-25 00:27:42' (length=19)
      public 'identifier' => string 'b47f2c82' (length=8)
      public 'status' => string 'New' (length=3)
      public 'tech' => string 'None' (length=4)
```

Comment: `$ticket->find()[0]->identifier` and `$ticket->find()[1]->identifier`. You can use a loop over `$ticket->find()[i]->identifier`.

Comment: I should have thought a little harder. Thank you.

Comment: Where does the `find()` method come from? If you're using a framework, there's probably a more direct method to achieve your goal.

Comment: If not, `array_column` can get you those values if you are using PHP 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to select the properties that you need from each item in the `array` returned by `find`:

```
$filteredFields = array_map(function ($item) {
    // Return whatever properties you want here:

    return [$item->tid, $item->$uid, $item->issue];
}, $ticket->find());
```

`$filteredFields` will be an `array` of `arrays`:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(1) "1"
        [1]=> string(2) "22"
        [2]=> string(8) "iPhone 7"
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(1) "2"
        [1]=> string(2) "22"
        [2]=> string(8) "iPhone 7"
    }
}
```

If you just need one of the properties, it may be easier to use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$subjectFields = array_column($ticket->find(), "subject");
```

This will return something that looks like this:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> string(8) "iPhone 8"
    [1]=> string(8) "iPhone 7"
}
```

You can also get an associative array indicating which field to use as the key with the third parameter:

```
$subjectsByTid = array_column($ticket->find(), "subject", "tid");
```

This will return:

```
array(2) {
    ["1"]=> string(8) "iPhone 8"
    ["2"]=> string(8) "iPhone 7"
}
```

Comment: When I `var_dump` the array map it does not return anything. That would be a must more helpful method when I need to return all the tickets in a table.

Comment: @TrentonTyler When you call `array_map`, the function you provide will be called for each item in the array you pass in, the one returned by `$ticket->find()`, and the value you return from that function, which in this example is another `array`, will be added to the `array` you are getting back as a result. If that's not working, I would suggest checking that the params you are trying to get  are accessible.